# Animals on movie sets - the cat in The Hateful Eight

Tags: production, the-hateful-eight

In *The Hateful Eight*, chapter five, when a few more people arrive at Minnie's Haberdashery we can see a cat wandering around.

> When they start killing almost everyone, no one hurts nor kills the cat nor the horses.

It is most likely that they didn't kill him, and that he is hiding for the rest of the movie.

I was suprised not to see him again, but I recognise Tarantino doesn't care about filming cats.

So my first question is: Does Quentin Tarantino like (or care) about animals? (I remember a horse being killed in *Django Unchained*, "Tarantino Style")

What makes me wonder, is that I usually see a line during the end credits, saying that "No animals were harmed [or whatever] while shooting the film", or something apporaching. But in those end credits, the only line was something like "Every animal was under the supervision of [Animal Protection Association]".

Which leads to my second question:
Is this common now not to mention that no animals were harmed? Or is this because at least one animal has been harmed?

Comment: The first question seems a bit odd, though.

Comment: That's because I'm an odd person ^^
But I don't think the question is. He doesn't hesitate to brutally kill human beings in his movies, and it's always depicted with violence. But I don't recall anything like that with animals, except for Django. So it seems fair to ask if he would show animals being murdered in the same way that he does with humans

Comment: "does so-and-so like cats?" doesn't seem like a very on-topic question. However, the "if the movie doesn't explicitly state no animals were harmed, was an animal harmed?" is an interesting question.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2080/49).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before answer your question I need to point it out the work of the [American Humane Association](http://www.americanhumane.org/animals/programs/no-animals-were-harmed/) (AHA) which started to advise Hollywood movie industry about the behavior of animals and humans, which they been doing since 1939 after the group began protesting the public release of the film Jesse James, because of a scene where a horse was forced to run off the edge of a cliff. The horse fell over 70 feet to the ground below and broke its spine, having to be put down afterwards.

So, first question is yes, Tarantino is very interested in the animal's health when they work with it; in a interview [with NPR](http://www.npr.org/2013/01/02/168200139/quentin-tarantino-unchained-and-unruly) he expressed:

> "***The only thing that I've ever watched in a movie that I wished I'd never seen is real-life animal death*** or real-life insect death in a movie (...) I don't like seeing animals murdered on screen. Movies are about make-believe. (...) I don't think there's any place in a movie for real death."

And to ensure this point, he mention the importance of the AHA in the movie set of *Django Unchained*:

So, to your second question, recently most movies put that they *don't hurt animals* or give bad treatment; what is clear is some of them just put the information (no animals hurt) when actually they did.

The Hollywood Reporter [made investigations](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/feature/) about some movies and found they almost killed animals; for example: Life of Pi, The Hobbit, the Zookeeper, among others. The AHA also explained some movies just use their authorization without a clear supervision of their staff.

Comment: @richard definately apples have been killed in that production